# server with nginx and laravel urls doesn't work

Tags: php, nginx, laravel

I just created my new server, and installed lemp.
All is good if I have a domain poiting to the right place.

the problem is that I want to work n a project with no domain, so I want to work with the ip and folder like this:

```
http://888.888.888.888/laravelProjectName/public/
```

this url works, but when I go to inner pages like:

```
http://888.888.888.888/laravelProjectName/public/about
```

the page goes to:

```
http://888.888.888.888/
```

sorry forgot to add the conf:

```
server {                                                                                                        
        listen 80;                                                                                              

        server_name 888.888.888.888/meeters/public;                                                              

        access_log /var/log/nginx/meeters/access.log;                                                           
        error_log /var/log/nginx/meeters/error.log;                                                             

        root /usr/share/nginx/www/meeters/public/;                                                              
        index index.php;                                                                                        

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

any ideas on how to fix the nginx configuration? or something else?

Comment: post your current nginx virtual host file (the one inside `sites-enabled` or `conf.d`)

Comment: the root path is `/usr/share/nginx/www/meeters/public/laravelProjectName/public/` ?

Comment: the root path is correct, as the normal page (index) loads correctly

Comment: my conf file doesn't catch inner pages in the domain

Comment: try replacing `/index.php?$args;` with `/index.php$request_uri$is_args$query_string`

Comment: sorry doesn't work....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45404/discussion-between-tzook-bar-noy-and-mohammad-abushady)